# Unity Firebase SignInAnonymously sometimes works and sometimes not

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have an issue with signing in anonymously into my Firebase database for my Unity game. I have a method for signing anonymously into the database and another one that reads the database and prints a json string.

```
public IEnumerator anonymousSignIn()
{
    var register = auth.SignInAnonymouslyAsync();

    yield return new WaitUntil(predicate: ()=> register.IsCompleted);
}

public IEnumerator readDatabase()
{
    var DBTask = DBreference.Child("users").GetValueAsync();

    yield return new WaitUntil(predicate: () => DBTask.IsCompleted);

    if (DBTask.Exception != null)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning(message: $"Failed to register task with {DBTask.Exception}");
    }
    else if (DBTask.Result.Value == null)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("No data found in the database");
    }
    else
    {
        DataSnapshot snapshot = DBTask.Result;
        string json = snapshot.GetRawJsonValue();
        Debug.Log(json);
    }
}
```

I then call these functions via a button in my Unity games using the method:

```
public void readButton()
{
    StartCoroutine(anonymousSign());
    StartCoroutine(readDatabase());
}
```

However, this sometimes works and other times It says permission denied and I don't understand why.
My database rules for reading are: `".read": "auth != null",`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same error.
After that, I changed the code

### From:

```
Auth.SignInAnonymouslyAsync().ContinueWith(task => { SignInAnonymously(task, "Guest"); });
```

### To:

```
Auth.SignInAnonymouslyAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task => { SignInAnonymously(task, "Guest"); });
```

Don't use Async for Anonymous Sign In, but run on Main Thread.

It worked for me!